# What's the maximum size of an nginx *.conf file?

Tags: nginx

Is there a limit? I can't find this info. anywhere.

If I wanted to inline an image (for testing purposes only) in an endpoint configured in my *.conf file, is there a limit?

I realize this is an odd question, but it'd be great to know this.

Comment: for what reason you would like to do something like that?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got into a hard limit recently in a project.

Indeed, the limit is 512k bytes per file.

You can get past this with includes.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at nginx configuration parsing function `ngx_conf_read_token()` function in `ngx_conf_file.c`, there seems to be a limit of 4096 bytes for a configuration directive's data.

I don't see any other limits on the configuration file size with a quick glance.